# Ionic 5 images that are present in files not showing when used in CSS background or img tag src

Tags: html, css, angular, image, ionic-framework

I've tried looking at solutions of other similar questions here, but I can't help but feel that this is specific to me using Ionic and/or Angular.
I have two files in my project directory, one called "bg.jpg" that is under app/images/home/bg.jpg, and one called "logo.png" that is in the directory of my home component HTML (app/home). In my CSS I used `background: url('../images/home/bg.jpg');` to get bg.jpg as a background, and, although it was a bit stubborn initially, it has been working fine.

Now for "logo.png", I am using `<img src="./logo.png">`, but I am getting `GET http://localhost:8100/logo.png 404 (Not Found)` on the console whenever I do `ìonic serve`. I've tried moving it to other directories, with no positive results. I've also restarted VS Code multiple times, but not much changed.

I really can't figure out what the problem is, as I've checked the path multiple times. I am using ionic router if that is of significance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please make sure your image is in
app_name/src/assets/bg.jpg
now you can give it src to image tag like src="assets/bg.jpg"

Comment: It worked, thank you very much! Very silly mistake on my part.